# Difference between jQuery and Axios PUT request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, axios

I am new to web development and I am working with a system that needs overhauling and development.

I am attempting to pull what is saved on a server as a "JSON" file to the front end and display the encoded data.

The "JSON" file includes text like the following:

```
{"name": "7.8-15.6kHz",data: [  [Date.UTC(2021, 9, 29, 0, 30, 12),0], [Date.UTC(2021, 9, 29, 0, 30, 12),0], [Date.UTC(2021, 9, 29, 1, 30, 59),0], [Date.UTC(2021, 9, 29, 2, 30, 17),0], [Date.UTC(2021, 9, 29, 3, 30, 15),0],
```

EDIT: I put "JSON" in quotes because this isn't json, however the file I am grabbing has a .json extension. This is the output of a microprocess somebody else wrote, and I am hoping to use this "JSON" file to pull data on the front end without having to manipulate the microprocess.

This obviously includes Javascript objects (passed as strings via php), as well as strings, and integers.

When I request this data via jQuery, the response is formatted as a Javascript object without needing to do anything to the response:

```
$.ajax({url:dataHTTP,
     dataType: "json",
     type:"POST",
     data:user,
     success:function(returnedData){
          console.log(returnedData)
          //Do some stuff with returnedData
}})
```

As I am migrating to REACT, I am trying to achieve the same with Axios:

```
const config = {
     headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
     }
 }
axios({
     method: 'post',
     url: dataURL,
     data:JSON.stringify(this.state.user),
     headers:config.headers
}).then((res) => {
     console.log(res.data); //this logs a string of the "JSON" file
     JSON.parse(res.data); //this throws an error
      
})
```

What is the difference here and how can I force Axios to treat this the same way as jQuery does??

Comment: The first snippet isn't JSON, it's code.

Comment: Are you trying to parse JSON to JSON? What is the error?